# Google Photos Auto-Backup Exclude folder

Tags: backup, google-now

I have Auto Backup enabled in Google Now for Photos.  I also have Local Folders enabled so that photos produced by apps other than the camera get backed up too.

However, this then includes photos and videos from folders that I don't want to backup.   The "Include Local Folders" seems to be an all or nothing option.

Is there a way to exclude folders individually?

I still want these folders to be recognised as media, just not backed up.

Comment: If anyone is looking to remove the folder from backups AND not have it recognized as media, you can add a ".nomedia" file in that directory. (Just leaving here in case others stumble on this page like I did, but don't want folders recognized as media).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should be able to select folder settings in the photos app. Per [support.google](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509?hl=en):

You can choose to automatically back up your Android's photo and video folders, including photos you've downloaded, screenshots you've taken, or photos saved by other apps.

> **Turn setting on or off** Open the  Photos app > touch the  menu
>   icon/button  > Settings > Auto Backup > check or uncheck Back up local
>   folders
>
> **Turn on or off for individual folders** Open the  Photos app > touch the
>   Photos menu icon at the top left > On Device > to the right of each
>   folder title, toggle the cloud icon to turn Auto Backup on or off for
>   that folder

Comment: Wow, thanks, I could not find that anywhere...

Comment: This no longer works. There is no cloud icon Now. It seems to be an all or nothing setting now.

Comment: If you go to the "on device" view in photos, there are cloud icons

Comment: This option should be easier to find without needing to google it like what I did..

Comment: @yincrash I do not see it too

Comment: You need to first turn on the settings for backing up `local folders`. Then you would be able to see the clouds in the `on device` screen

Comment: Is there any way to disable for new folders by default? Right now it auto enabled any new folders that are being added (be it by apps or manually)

Comment: @ChenAsraf it *should* prompt whether to include new folders or not when it detects them